# How to allow resource owners to pre-authorise selected clients using OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Let's say you have a web service with many OAuth2/OpenID Connect clients that supports regular 3 legged OAuth.

Users of this service (resource owners) would also like to be able to select clients to grant OAuth permissions to *from within the service itself.*.  For example, by checking a series of checkboxes.

There appears to be no standard way of doing this.  As in, there is no defined way of (a) kicking off an OAuth flow from the resource server or (b) sharing already generated authorization codes and/or tokens with clients.

Is there a standard I've missed?  Do other services do this?  What's the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: It is typically  the client that sends the request for authentication.   If you have a list of clients i suppose you could display this list to the users and have them grant access.   However i am not sure how you think the clients will then be able to handle the access grant that they didn't request.

Comment: @DalmTo That is indeed the question - is there a standard way of specifying how clients should handle these service initiated requests?  Or does everyone else "roll their own" method?

Answer (score 0):

[User Managed Access](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/rec-uma-core.html) provides such a solution.

"A typical example is the following: a web user (an end-user resource owner) can authorize a web or native app (a client) to gain one-time or ongoing access to a protected resource containing his home address stored at a "personal data store" service (a resource server), by telling the resource server to respect access entitlements issued by his chosen cloud-based authorization service (an authorization server)."